# Implment Rijndael/SHA1 encryption with PKCS7 padding in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, encryption, plsql

I'm trying to encrypt a data string in Oracle PL/SQL to send to a vendor. The vendor requires the data to be encrypted with the following information:

- HashAlgorithm = Rijndael/SHA1
- keySize = 256
- blockSize = 256
- paddingType = PKCS7

They have also provided the following C# implementation:

```
private String AES_encrypt(string Input, string AES_Key, string AES_IV) {
    var aes = new RijndaelManaged();
    aes.KeySize = 256;
    aes.BlockSize = 256;
    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_Key);
    aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(AES_IV);

    var encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
    byte[] xBuff = null;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] xXml = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Input);
            cs.Write(xXml, 0, xXml.length);
        }

        xBuff = ms.ToArray();
    }

    String Output = Convert.ToBase64String(xBuff);
    return Output;
}
```

I need to implement this in Oracle PL/SQL, and here's what I've been able to get so far:

```
PROCEDURE P_encrypt
IS
    input_string VARCHAR2 (200);
    encrypted_raw RAW(2000);
    num_key_bytes NUMBER := 256/8;
    key_bytes_raw RAW(32) := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('aAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaAaA'); -- 32 character string equivalent to the AES_Key in the C# code
    encryption_type PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                                 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                                 + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_NONE;
BEGIN
    --
    -- input string gets generated here
    --

    -- now to encrypt the string
    encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
        (
            src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(input_string, 'AL32UTF8'),
            typ => encryption_type,
            key => key_bytes_raw,
            iv => utl_raw.cast_to_raw('A 44 character string') -- equivalent to AES_IV in the C# code
        );
END P_encrypt;
```

Unfortunately, my implementation does not seem to work correctly. Could anyone give me some guidance on how to properly implement this in Oracle PL/SQL? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pro-tip: Rijndael with a block size of 256 bits is **not** AES. Also, saying it "does not work correctly" does not provide any information.

Comment: Sorry, the vender just says they can't decipher it. That's all the information I get back from them. I was lead to believe from other implementations that Rijndael is AES, is that incorrect? What's the difference?

Comment: Rijndael with a block size of 128 is AES.  Rijndael with any other block size is not.